# RadTreeView can't be found at in OnClientNodeClicked event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, telerik, domready, radtreeview

I'm using Telerik RadTreeView, and I've provided a JavaScript function for its `OnClientNodeClicked` property:

```
<telerik:RadTreeView 
    ID="pagesTree" 
    runat="server" 
    OnClientNodeClicked='onPageSelected' 
    ClientIDMode='static'>
</telerik:RadTreeView>

$telerik.$(document).ready(function () {
    onPageSelected(); // To run the onPageSelected function on DOM ready
}

function onPageSelected(e){
   var pagesTree = $find('pagesTree');
   // pagesTree is null here in IE8 for the manual execution on DOM ready
}
```

What I do, is to manually run the `onPageSelected` on telerik's DOM ready. However, `pagesTree` variable is null in that time. What's wrong? This problem happens only in IE8 (not even IE9, and we don't support IE7 and below)

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely due to the fact that you're just using `$find('pagesTree')`. You have to keep in mind that the ID you set for your ASP.NET server-side control (Telerik or non-Telerik) will generate a ClientID. You can grab the proper client-side object by doing the following:

```
var pagesTree = $find('<%= pagesTree.ClientID %>');
```

When the page gets rendered <%= pagesTree.ClientID %> will be rendered as a string with the proper ClientID of your control.

Comment: `ClientIDMode` is set to static, and as I see in Firebug, the element indeed has the `pagesTree` id.